# Openlayers: with a list of features, how can I organize them by distance from a coordinate

Tags: openlayers

Let's say I'm using openlayers (5) and I have an array of features, they can all be from different layer sources, and I have a set of coordinates.  What is the best way to sort that array so that the closest feature to that coordinate is at the top, furthest is at the bottom?

I was looking at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Cluster-Cluster.html#getClosestFeatureToCoordinate originally, but that only gives me 1 feature and not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: It will probably have to be done the long way - iterate through the layers and their features and call `feature.getClosestPoint(coordinate)` on each one, calculate the distance from the coordinate to the returned closest point on the feature using pythagoras (assuming they are close enough together that true scale doesn't matter as it would if some were in Greenland and some in Africa) and push a `{ feature, distance }` object to an array.  The object array containing the features can the be sorted using `array.sort(function(a, b){return a.distance - b.distance});`

Comment: your solution definitely works, but yeah i was hoping for a shorter route.  heads up to anyone else that wants to use it, it's actually feature.getGeometry().getClosestPoint(coordinate)